# Differentiating between strings using javascript regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to differentiate between strings urls using javascript regex for example, i want to find out whether a page is category or product page?

```
function whatIsThePage(_str){
   if(_str.match("")){
    alert("category page");
   }
  else if(_str.match("")){
    alert("product page");
  }
  else{
   alert("some other page");
  }  
}

// some examples

var someUrl = whatIsThePage("brands/nike") // alert "category page"
var someUrl2 = whatIsThePage("/brands/nike/someproduct") // alert "product page"
var someUrl3 = whatIsThePage("/brands/adidas") // alert "category page"
var someUrl4 = whatisThePage("/checkout/success") // alert "some other page"
```

Comment: So category and product pages start with `brands` or `/brands`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills start with /brands sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the thing that distinguishes a product page is that is has a third level you can do

```
if(_str.match(/\/brands\/[^/]+\/.+/)) {
    alert('product');
} else if(_str.match(/\/brands\/.+/)) {
    alert('category');
} else {
    alert('something else');
}
```

This says match the string `/brands/`, followed by any character that isn't a `/` one of more times, followed by `/`, followed by any other character.  If it matches alert product otherwise just check if it matches `/brand/` followed by any other character, if so alert category.

Take a look at http://tinyurl.com/kf5g6s8 to understand the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer a slightly different solution. If all you're concerned about is the number of 'levels' in the string, you could just split the string on `/` characters and count the number of elements:

```
function whatIsThePage(_str) {
    var pageTypes = [,,,"category page", "product page"];
    var pageType = pageTypes[_str.split('/').length] || "something else";
    alert(pageType);
}

whatIsThePage("/brands");                   // "something else"
whatIsThePage("/brands/nike");              // "category page"
whatIsThePage("/brands/nike/someproduct");  // "product page"
```

Note that this is pretty simple implementation. If you only want to restrict this to strings where the first 'level' is the exact string `"brands"` or if you need to exclude strings where the last level is an empty string (e.g. `/brands/nike/`), then you'd have to tweak it a bit. Still, for a problem like this, it seems like a slightly more elegant solution than regular expressions in my opinion.